# Automatic tag inside DB in TIA Portal

Tags: plc, siemens, tia-portal

i started working on my project which use S7-1200 integrated webserver to display data from PLC. I want to make library of component for my project and i will use these components quite regularly. I already wrote web part, which read data from one DB.

To my question, it is possible to somehow created specifically named tags inside DB from putting FC from custom library?

For example, i have FC with tags Input1 and Output2. After i put FC from library and somehow give it name, i want in DB tags name_Input1 and name_Output2. It doesn't need to be completely automatic, i just asking if is there some better method that create these tags manually. Alternatively to create new tags with prefix.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using FB instead of FC. When you create an instance of a function block TIA Portal automatically creates a DB with tags declared in FB.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-instance dB is the way tp GP for you.
"instance-db-name".tag